# Angular service return Observable from .then

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I'm trying to return the current authentication status in a service method. (The code works except for the return.) I'm not familiar with the call to .then inside .map and I can't figure out how to return an Observable.

```
public getSignedInStatus(): Observable<boolean> {
        this._gauth.getAuth().map(auth => {
            auth.then(function() {
                return Observable.of(auth.isSignedIn.get());
            });
        });
    }
```

In the docs, there's a subscribe call. I tried changing it to .map but it didn't help.

```
this._gauth.getAuth()
        .subscribe(auth => {
```

The error is `"A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value."`

I want to be able to call the method from any component. Something like this:

```
return this._userService.getSignedInStatus()
      .map(
        signedIn => {    
          if (signedIn === true) {
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        },
        error => console.error('Error getting user status')
      );
```

And in an AuthGuard, like this:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    this._userService.getSignedInStatus()
    .subscribe( response => {
        const status = response.isSignedIn.get();
        if (status === true) {
           return true;
        } else {
           this.router.navigate(['/signin']);
           return false;
        }
    },
    error => {
       console.error('Error getting user status');
       return false;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: There are some issue with your code . What is the return type of `this._gauth.getAuth()` ? if the return value of `public getSignedInStatus(): ` is `Observable<boolean>` then you need to use `subscribe()` in your component class to consume the service like `return this._userService.getSignedInStatus()
      .subscribe(`

Comment: Thanks. the return type is Observable<gapi.auth2.GoogleAuth>. But getSignedInStatus() won't build, so I haven't gotten to the call from the component yet.

Comment: what is the error you are getting currently when using `map`?

Comment: @Niladri the error is in the question. The return is not valid. The error is "A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
public getSignedInStatus(): Observable<gapi.auth2.GoogleAuth> {
    return this._gauth.getAuth();
}
```

And in your route guard you subscribe to the observable and you return it

```
return this._userService.getSignedInStatus()
  .subscribe( response => {    
      return response.isSignedIn.get();
  },
  error => {
     return false
  });
```

Comment: Thanks. that looks good, I'll try it in a component. When I tried it just now in an AuthGuard, I got this error: "error TS2420: Class 'AuthGuard' incorrectly implements interface 'CanActivate'.
  Types of property 'canActivate' are incompatible.
    Type '(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => void' is not assignable to type '(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => boolean | Promise<boolean> | Obser...'.
      Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean>'."

Comment: Oh if you are using it in a route guard then you should return the value. Try it with the commented return statements, and ditch someVarInComponent.

Comment: I appreciate the help. Even with the commented out version, I'm getting the same error. "'AuthGuard' incorrectly implements interface 'CanActivate'.  Types of property 'canActivate' are incompatible."

Comment: Can you show me the full code of your route guard's canActivate function?

Comment: added it to the question.

Comment: I belive you need return before this._userService.getSignedInStatus(), which you originally had before I confused you :D
I will update the answer as well.

Comment: thx. If I add return and also change subscribe to map, then it builds. I have to head out. I'll test more later.